# Memory issues with GraphDB 7.0

Tags: semantic-web, triplestore, graphdb

I am trying to load a dataset to GraphDB 7.0. I wrote a Python script to transform and load the data on Sublime Text 3. The program suddenly stopped working and closed, the computer threatened to restart but didn't, and I lost several hours worth of computing as GraphDB doesn't let me query the inserts. This is the error I get on GraphDB:

```
The currently selected repository cannot be used for queries due to an error:

org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryException: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is not enough memory for the entity pool to load: 65728645 bytes are required but there are 0 left. Maybe cache-memory/tuple-index-memory is too big.
```

I set the JVM as follows:

```
-Xms8g
-Xmx9g
```

I don't exactly remember what I set as the values for the cache and index memories. How do I resolve this issue?

For the record, the database I need to parse has about 300k records. The program shut shop at about 50k. What do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you configure GraphDB's entity pool? Is it using the default (classic) config, or the transactional/transactional-simple config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the workbench and check the amount of memory you have given to cache memory.

Xmx should be a value that is enough for

```
cache-memory + memory-for-queries + entity-pool-hash-memory
```

sadly the latter cannot be calculated easily because it depends on the number of entities in the repository. You will either have to:

1. Increase the java memory with a bigger value for Xmx
2. Decrease the value for cache memory